# How to convert a DbSet to an observableCollection in WPF?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4.1, wpfdatagrid

I have a database which is created using EF4.1 code first. The data context is as follow:

```
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

I want to show address for a user by binding the `users.Address` to a datagrid in a ViewModel scenario. The problem is that I cannot convert `Users.Address` into a list that I can bind a collection into it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some links on how to use the [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) property of `DbSet<>` for data binding.

[Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 7: Local Data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx)

[EF Feature CTP5: Code First Model with Master-Detail WPF Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/08/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-model-with-master-detail-wpf-application.aspx)

Comment: Links are currently due for migration